# Is Token Program 2022 Live?

Tags: spl-token

so I wanted to enquire that whether the token program 2022 is live and is being used by in place of the original token program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Token-2022 Program has been deployed on mainnet](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022) having the program ID `TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb`.

You can provide support for Token-2022 in you program, however, the program is currently under multiple audits to ensure safety of funds.